# Getting value of fact linked table

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 tables which are not directly linked. They are linked by a fact table.
[Table structure snipset here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LreZE.png)

I wanna now list all products with its last sale amount (independent when).

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    '_product'[ProductID],
    '_product'[ProductName],
    "LastSaleAmount", [LastSaleAmount]
)
```

If they would be directly connected I would use the measures:

```
    MEASURE [LastSaleAmount] =
        SUMMARIZE (
            FILTER (
                '_sale',
                '_sale'[SaleDate] = MAX ( _Sale[SaleDate] )
            ),
            "kk", MAX ( '_sale'[Amount] )
        )
```

But how can I get the sale amount when they are not directly linked like in my structure?
Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Merge Fact Table and Product Table using ProductID in Power Query
2. Merge Fact Table and Sales Table using SaleID in Power Query
3. Merge above two tables using ProductID and SaleID in Power Query
4. Write your measure on this new Table to get desired output